# Good practice for text styling in HTML5

Tags: html, css, semantic-markup

I'm creating a webpage that includes a mixture of different types of text-- bold, underlined, small, left-aligned, center-aligned, right-aligned, etc., and in trying to abstract the styling from the HTML, I'm trying to do away with `<b>` and `<u>` tags. The result is defining classes (such as "bold", "underline", "small", etc.) and using CSS to provide the styling. However, this makes the HTML much more verbose with divs and spans that have things like `class="rightAlign small bold underline"`. Is there a better way to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: You could always combine several properties into one class. For example, if your titles use `rightAligh small bold underline`, then create a class `title` with all of those properties.

Comment: Are you working with fixed data or a cms like wordpress for example?

Comment: You might look into Less, which I believe offers some interesting css merging options.

Comment: The content is dynamic based on the user. The problem is that there aren't many instances where I can combine properties. Sometimes it's plain small text, other times it's bold and small, other times it's just bold, bold and underlined, etc.. so either the HTML will be verbose or the CSS would be.

Comment: This does not sound like a constructive question, and it is based on misunderstandings, and the question does not describe the real situation (a comment tells that the content is “dynamic based on the user”).

Answer (score 5):

You're kind of missing the point of CSS.

You want to separate the markup from the styling, not combine the two.

How is `<div class="bold">` any better than `<div style="font-weight: bold;">`?

Maybe less typing, but it has the same effect. If you want to change your layout later on, you've made it so that you need to go and modify the CSS and the markup.

It's better to group the properties.

So for instance, instead of having

```
<div class="rightAlign small bold underline">
```

have

```
<div class="title">

.title {
   text-align: right;
   font-weight: bold;
   text-decoration: underline;
   font-size: small;
 }
```

This way you can change `title` later on if you want, without having to go through your pages and modify the markup as well.

Comment: And don't forget that you can spec multiple classes in one selector, so that several classes can all have similarities. So, if you have a set of classes you know you'll always want to be bold, you can spec them all at once, a la `.title, .caption, .mast h2 { /* specs */ }`

Comment: Thanks. I get what you're saying, but it's just that there are many combinations of the styles that I'm trying to use, so it's difficult to just combine them once and use that class wherever it's used, since many of them are unique.

Comment: @TNC, I see what you're saying, but without knowing exactly what it is you're doing it's hard to suggest an alternative. You said it depends on the user, how so? Would user specific stylesheets help? Keep one set of markup, and then apply different stylesheets as needed?

Comment: There are several strategies to deal with these issues, and you really have to find your own balance. In general, however, if you find yourself repeating the same code more than 2-3 times, you really should encapsulate as many of the similarities into classes as possible. Some people like to put all font-specs in one set of classes, and color-specs or box-dimensions in another set. There's no 100% "right answer" except for "do what looks like it will reduce repetition... and realize you'll have to recode this all eventually!" :)

Comment: @Brandon the styling is not dependent on the user, as the bold/underlined/etc. portions are for general labels; the content that follows is dynamic. So user-specific stylesheets are not necessary.

Comment: @TNC The effect here is a more modular approach to your code. If you have so many unique styles then perhaps you should examine why you think you need that many styles. A page should generally match with itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  and  for bold and italics respectively, but only if the information being bolded/italicized is actually important.

If you have an area that is small, bold and underline, and this area repeats across the site multiple times, it would make more sense to define that area with it's own class, and apply all those styles at once.  For example a meta area in a wordpress that has the post by date, and author name.  This "meta" type of area is often italics, smaller font, different color and sometimes even a different font.  Give that area `class="meta"` instead of giving it `class="small italics geneva blue"`

Comment: Please don't use string for bold unless the text is important, nor em for italics unless you are trying to stress the word or phrase contained within it. You are abusing the semantics of those elements. Use spans if all you want do is apply styling within a paragraph. And you are mistaken, `<b>` and `<u>` are both valid in HTML5

Comment: `b` and `u` are not deprecated in HTML 5: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/HTML5/HTML5_element_list

Comment: Thanks for the clarity, edited for accuracy.  The only time I ever edit text styling is to make something important stand out, which is why I use strong and em, should have been more clear. =)